# Service to allow Dropbox upload for non-Dropbox User

Tags: dropbox

Is there a method or service that I could use to allow a non-Dropbox user to upload a document to one of my Dropbox folders without creating an account of their own?

I get documents weekly from new contributors, many of whom don't have a Dropbox account. It would be very convenient if there were a way for them to send files to my Dropbox shared folders without having to go through the process of setting up an account and installing the Dropbox client.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8591/web-write-only-drop-box

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to using e-mail...

**[Send To Dropbox](http://sendtodropbox.com/)** gives you a unique e-mail address. Any attachments sent to that address are added to your Dropbox.

***or***

**[MailDrop](http://getmaildrop.dreamhosters.com/)** monitors your e-mail client (for a keyword or a specific folder) and, when triggered, uploads any attachments to Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you choose to sync a folder and make that folder avaliable on the web.
I'm thinking about having a webserver (like XAMPP/LAMP) installed on your PC, and the folder is accessible on the web.

Then you can simply use a html/php script to protect the folders (for each contributor) with password, and as soon as they upload stuff, you sync them. (and they get avaliable on Dropbox.)

However, you should have a pretty good anti-virus (Like Avast? No ad intended.) installed since they can upload virtually anything. (Except if you specify that stuff too in your php script.)

Answer (score 0):

**Dropbox Uploader** lets other people upload files to your Dropbox (if you have your own website and can run PHP).

[Setup instructions](http://www.ampercent.com/dropbox-uploader-allow-users-upload-files-dropbox-account/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Dropbox Forms](http://www.jotform.com/dropbox/)** is a service of JotForm that allows you to create forms to embed (nearly) anywhere that people can use to upload files to your Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [dbinbox](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57598556-285/let-non-dropbox-users-dropbox-you-with-dbinbox/).

Choose a username and link dbinbox to your dropbox account. You can set an access code. Non-dropbox users can then upload files via the custom link 'http://dbinbox.com/USERNAME'